# Writing unit test for the azure redis cache in nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis, sinon, stub, azure-redis-cache

I am trying to write a unit test case using mocha framework, where I have to mock an azure redis cache...Can someone help me on how to mock cache for unit test case purpose using node.js.

```
    const redis = require('redis'); 
    const redisHostName = process.env['hostName'];
    const redisPort = process.env['port'];
    const redisKey = process.env['key'];

    let client = redis.createClient(redisPort, redisHostName, { auth_pass: redisKey, tls: { serverName: redisHostName } });



    async function getKeyValue(key, ctx) {
        context = ctx;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            client.get(key, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                resolve(err);
            }
                resolve(result);
            }); 
        });
    }
getKeyValue();
```

Comment: So, you want to test `getKeyValue` function?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.js`

```js
const redis = require('redis');
const redisHostName = process.env['hostName'];
const redisPort = process.env['port'];
const redisKey = process.env['key'];

let client = redis.createClient(redisPort, redisHostName, { auth_pass: redisKey, tls: { serverName: redisHostName } });

async function getKeyValue(key, ctx) {
  context = ctx;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.get(key, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
        return resolve(err);
      }
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
}

exports.getKeyValue = getKeyValue;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const redis = require('redis');

describe('60870408', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    process.env['hostName'] = '127.0.0.1';
    process.env['port'] = 6379;
    process.env['key'] = 'test';
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    delete require.cache[require.resolve('./')];
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it('should get value', async () => {
    const client = {
      get: sinon.stub().callsFake((key, callback) => callback(null, 'elsa')),
    };
    const createClientStub = sinon.stub(redis, 'createClient').returns(client);
    const { getKeyValue } = require('./');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(createClientStub, '6379', '127.0.0.1', {
      auth_pass: 'test',
      tls: { serverName: '127.0.0.1' },
    });
    const actual = await getKeyValue('name', {});
    sinon.assert.match(actual, 'elsa');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(client.get, 'name', sinon.match.func);
  });

  it('should handle error', async () => {
    const mError = new Error('network');
    const client = {
      get: sinon.stub().callsFake((key, callback) => callback(mError)),
    };
    const createClientStub = sinon.stub(redis, 'createClient').returns(client);
    const { getKeyValue } = require('./');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(createClientStub, '6379', '127.0.0.1', {
      auth_pass: 'test',
      tls: { serverName: '127.0.0.1' },
    });
    const actual = await getKeyValue('name', {});
    sinon.assert.match(actual, mError);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(client.get, 'name', sinon.match.func);
  });
});
```

unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
  60870408
    ✓ should get value
    ✓ should handle error


  2 passing (28ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```